# Property group By is a foreign key that references to another table

Tags: grails

I want to write a query that makes the sum of an attribut 'scale'  group by a proprety that is a foreign key references to another table. I want to know what can i write in the  groupProperty('').

```
     def moyenneMatiere = ContentEvaluation.createCriteria().list {

     projections {
   //  groupProperty('content?.chapter.section.subject')

     groupProperty('????')
      sum('scale')

    }

   }
```

I neeed your helps please, Thanks :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since we havn't seen you FK relationship in the domain .So assumptions based code:
Assume fk relationship code inside your domain ContentEvaluation ,has property

### Domain :

```
OtherTable content
```

### Query:

```
def contentEvalutionList = ContentEvaluation.createCriteria().list {
      projection{
           content{
                      groupProperty('chapter')
           }
           sum('scale')
       }



  }
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: @Hasna Am so glad ..:)